# Unit testing method with method reference as parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method that takes as parameter an object and a method reference to that object to collect the integers in a collection from that object. The code works fine but I am unable to unit test with mockito on the when() method.

```
public class UserCredentials {

  private Integer accountId;

  private Integer customerNameId;
}

public class UserCredentialsUtil {

  public List<Integer> userCredentialsGetter(
      final List<UserCredentials> userCredentials,
      final Function<UserCredentials, Integer> func) {
    return userCredentials.stream().map(func).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

My unit test basically returns to me an empty List.

```
  @Mock
  private UserCredentialsUtil userCredentialsUtil;

final List<Integer> accountIds = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

        when(
        this.userCredentialsUtil.userCredentialsGetter(
            userCredentials,
         UserCredentials::getAccountId)).thenReturn(accountIds);
```

I know this isn't a problem with my setup because if I change the UserCredentialsGetter to

```
  public List<Integer> userCredentialsGetter(
      final List<UserCredentials> userCredentials) {
    return userCredentials.stream().map(UserCredentials::getAccountId).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

And the test method to.

```
        when(
        this.userCredentialsUtil.userCredentialsGetter(
            userCredentials)).thenReturn(accountIds);
```

This works fine. I am guessing I need to pass something else then the method reference as parameter for my first test, but I have been unfortunate in finding someone else going into this case even though it seems pretty common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With mockito, you need to make sure that the method you pass into your `when` statement is the same that is passed in by the actual method. Based on your example, you are using `UserCredentials::getAccountId` and `UserCredentials::accountId` (possibly a typo).

You may want to consider using different argument matchers instead:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;

when(userCredentialsUtil.userCredentialsGetter(eq(userCredentials), any()).thenReturn(accountIds);
```

Comment: Yes a typo sorry. Maybe matchers will do it.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)